# Custom PickerView iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have already implemented PickerView, but I want to custom it like Alarm Clock app.

[image]

You can see that every component row has "Hour" or "Minute". I want to set it "Hour" and "Minute" to stand here, and every element which is not chosen, they don't have "Hour" or "Minute", just the one is chosen has "Hour" or "Minute".
How to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class StoryAddViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet var titleTextField: TextField!
  @IBOutlet var hashtagsTextField: TextField!
  @IBOutlet var createButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet var timePickerView: UIPickerView!
  var timePickerDataBase = [ ["1", "2" , "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"], ["1", "2" , "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26" , "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"] ]
  var hour = String()
  var minute = String()

  var story: Story?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Add new story"
    view.backgroundColor = Colors.primaryBackgroundColor
    (tabBarController as! SLTabBarController).toggleTabBar(animated: false, showed: false)

    createButton.backgroundColor = Colors.tintColor
    createButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if story == nil {
      story = Story.create(getDatabase())
    }

    titleTextField.text = story?.title
    hashtagsTextField.text = story?.hashtags.joinWithSeparator(", ")
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    (tabBarController as! SLTabBarController).toggleTabBar(animated: true, showed: true)
  }

  @IBAction func handleViewTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.endEditing(true)
  }

  @IBAction func handleCreateButtonTap(sender: UIButton) {
    story?.title = titleTextField.text!
    story?.hashtags = hashtagsTextField.text!.split("\\s*,\\s*")

    try! story?.save()
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
  }

// MARK: handle picker view

  func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return timePickerDataBase.count
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return timePickerDataBase[component].count
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return timePickerDataBase[component][row]
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    if component == 0 {
      pickerLabel.text = timePickerDataBase[component][row] + "   Hour"
      pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 25)
      pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    } else {
      pickerLabel.text = timePickerDataBase[component][row] + "   Minute "
      pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 25)
      pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    }
    return pickerLabel
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 140
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(component)
    print(row)
    switch component {
    case 0:
      hour = timePickerDataBase[component][row]
      print(hour)
    case 1:
      hour = timePickerDataBase[component][row]
      print(minute)
    default:
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to say, only the selected value should have "hours", and "minutes", and all others should just have numbers? If so, I would suggest you do it another way, because refreshing the values while it's rotating wouldn't work very well

Comment: If you want to refresh values dynamically then checkout my answer. Otherwise I'd suggest have one picker, then "hours" label, then another picker and "minutes" label....or, have the first and default values like 0H: 0M, then the rest just numbers

Comment: If I use 2 picker view, every thing is easy, I only have to add 2 label next to them.

Comment: exactly, that's how I'd do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest changing the value of the fields dynamically the way I think you're trying to do (it would look strange), but if you REALLY had to, you should reload all data in

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // reload the data source or save current value
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents() // <---- use this to reload picker 
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    // setup the cells how you want to based on data source / current value
}
```